# sshd is already running though keeps trying to start

Tags: ssh, centos7

I have a Centos 7 server and sshd is running and accepting connections just fine.

The problem is, that `messages` log keeps reporting failed sshd startup attempts and `secure` log keeps reporting that sshd can't start because port 22 is in use.

messages;

> Mar 15 12:03:01 ded2100 systemd[1]: Starting Session 10614 of user root.
>   Mar 15 12:03:05 ded2100 systemd[1]: sshd.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
>   Mar 15 12:03:05 ded2100 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenSSH server daemon.
>   Mar 15 12:03:05 ded2100 systemd[1]: Unit sshd.service entered failed state.
>   Mar 15 12:03:05 ded2100 systemd[1]: sshd.service failed.

secure;

> Mar 15 12:01:34 ded2100 sshd[14947]: error: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Address already in use.
>   Mar 15 12:01:34 ded2100 sshd[14947]: error: Bind to port 22 on :: failed: Address already in use.

Today my server failed. SSH went as well requiring a hard reboot and I want to make sure sshd is as solid as it can be so I can rest assured if it *can* be up, it will be up.

Thanks.

**EDIT**
My sshd_config is here - https://gist.github.com/cbiggins/3cb4fcc1af25da63e89b1fab2eb7d57c

**EDIT #2**

```
[root@ded2100 log]# ss -p -o state listening '( sport = :ssh )'
Netid  Recv-Q Send-Q                                  Local Address:Port                                                   Peer Address:Port
tcp    0      128                                                 *:ssh                                                               *:*                     users:(("sshd",pid=1956,fd=3))
tcp    0      128                                                :::ssh                                                              :::*                     users:(("sshd",pid=1956,fd=4))
```

Comment: Run `ss -p -o state listening '( sport = :ssh )'` to see what is listening on the port. Requires root.

Comment: Looks like sshd is somehow already running. Kill the given PID and then `systemctl restart` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [known bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1381997), that `systemd` is unable to keep track of running service with RHEL7.3/CentOS7.3.

Especially, this is problem of services with `Type=forking`. Systemd  starts the service, checks the PID file (which is not written yet in some cases) and considers the service as failed. Then tries to start the service again, which obviously fails.

The update is on the way. To resolve the problem in one-shot, just kill the running `sshd` (pid `1956` in your case) and start a new one with `systemctl start sshd`.

Comment: Does that mean that openssh in RHEL is getting rebased to 7.4?

Comment: It is unrelated to the OpenSSH version. It is only problem with systemd, service file and SD_NOTIFY functionality (which is not in upstream).  But yes, it looks like that.

Comment: I was referring to your comment in the bug report.

Comment: Thanks. The server had to be rebooted overnight and it would appear that the reboot has resolved the issue based on this bug and your post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! Fist I did:

```
[root@xxx ~]# ss -panetl | grep :22
LISTEN     0      128          *:22                       *:*                   users:(("sshd",pid=20453,fd=3)) ino:218041529 sk:ffff8dcb94b43e00 <->
LISTEN     0      128         :::22                      :::*                   users:(("sshd",pid=20453,fd=4)) ino:218041531 sk:fff
```

Then I kill the process and restart sshd. This work for me.